# Django profiles - adding extra objects to detail view

Tags: django

Upon extending the excellent django project django-profiles (found on https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home) I stumbled upon something which I have been trying to solve for days.

The idea is fairly simple.  I have users, which have user profiles (object UserProfile, linked to User).  Now I added a new object to my project, Employment, which also links to the User object.

```
class Employment(models.Model):
    """
    A class to describe the relationship of employment, past or present, between an employee and an organization.

    """

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.function

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/recycling/employment/%i/" % self.id

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    date_start = models.DateField('Start date of employment', help_text="Please use the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.", null=True, blank=True)
    date_end = models.DateField('End date of employment', help_text="Please use the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.", null=True, blank=True)
    function = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    present_job = models.BooleanField()


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    A class representing a the profile of a user.  Needs to be generic enough to involve both employees as employers.

    """

    def _get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('profiles_profile_detail', (), { 'username': self.user.username })

    # Link person to user
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, null=True)

    registration_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I would like to have a page (detail view) where I can show the UserProfile and also all employment for a specific user.
I figured that adding extra_context is the way to go and this works eg.:

```
('^profiles/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.profile_detail', {'extra_context': {'employment_list': Employment.objects.all(),}}),
```

The problem I am facing however is that I would like to have user-specific objects (thus filtering) and not just all().
One pitfall is that the django-profiles project still works with functions as views, not classes, so subclassing is not an option.  Another attention point is that the view should not be cached, so that if a user adds another employment object and is redirected to the details page, this change should be reflected.
It would be nice to find a solution for this without adapting the django-profiles code itself...

Thanks for your help!

---

Found a way of doing this, turned out to be fairly simple.  I created a new view which generates a list with a filter.  Pass this list in extra_context to the view defined in the profiles application and done...

```
def detail_userprofile_view(request, username):
    """
    Returns a detail view including both the User Profile and the Employments linked to the user.
    """

    employment_list = Employment.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    context_dict = { 'employment_list': employment_list,}

    return profile_detail(request, username, extra_context=context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always write a new view. Something simple like:

urls

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<username>\w+)/$', profiles.views.profile_detail, name='profile_detail'),
```

views

```
def profile_detail(request, username):
    context_dict = {}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
    employment = get_object_or_404(Employment, user=user)

    context_dict = { 'user': user,
                     'profile':profile,
                     'employment':employment,
    }
    return render_to_response('details.html', context_dict, RequestContext(request))
```

Now in your template you can go `{{ user.first_name }}` or `{{ profile }}` or `{{ employment.organization }}` etc...

Comment: Well, there are some functionalities in the django-profiles view that I would like to keep...  Nothing spectacular and I could just write my own view, but that goes against the DRY principle.  But thanks for the suggestion!